# Admob rewarded video Ad Failed to load

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I am trying to integrate admob rewarded ad in my app but it always shows ad failed to load and the following error comes up on logcat

```
 Fail to instantiate adapter com.google.DummyAdapter
```

I also tried to run the sample rewarded video app on github provided in the admob rewarded doc but same error comes up.
I followed the exact procedure as provided in the admob documentation, but still nothing happens at all. Anybody knows what the problem is? or Is there anybody who has already implemented it?
I searched and something called meditation adapter i found about which i have no idea.
Any other suggestion might be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using test ads id you just need to go to the Build> Clean Project
and reinstall the application.
if you are using your own Admob video ad id then I suggest you to wait
the ads will start displaying after few hours depending upon your country.

Comment: Yeah it did, probably it took over a week to show up ads.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case my App target sdk version less then 14 so i was getting this error.

Please change your package name then try again or check your build sdk version and target sdk version.

Comment: It was a serving issue, which is now resolved automatically and for that I did nothing. Btw my app is on playstore so i cannot go back changing my package name or id. But thanks anyway for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score -1):

In admob sometimes the video was not found, being loaded from a third party (admob) google and gave a failed to load error. So the solution is when the video fails to load, you have to load another third party video key (in mobi) add in admob account and initialize it.